# What Class/Method's is used to write to the SysOutGoingEmailTable from an alert notification?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

When creating an alert you can setup if you want the user to receive an email when the alert happens. What class/method deals with writing the record to the `SysOutGoingEmailTable`.I thought the `EventActionEmail` class would be used, specifically the `execute` method, which in return calls SysEmailTable::sendMail() to insert a record into the `SysOutGoingEmailTable`. After doing some editing on the `EventActionEmail` Class and adding some info-log's for testing purposes it seems that the Class isn't even being used to write to the outgoing table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It **IS** `\Classes\EventActionEmail\execute` that does the emails.  Have you rebuilt your CIL after adding your infologs?  Where are you looking for the infologs?  I'd think the BatchJobHistory form (log button) would be where to start.

Comment: An Incremental CIL did the trick. Thanks for reassuring me that it was indeed the execute method that handled the event emails.

Comment: Funny thing is I barely read your post and just thought I'd dig around and track down where the emails were sent from, and after digging and finding the method, I came back and read that you were referring exactly to what I found!  Glad it worked or I'd have been a little lost.